# Blackjack Hall of Fame Voting

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Every year a bunch of famous blackjack players get together and vote on who gets into the Blackjack Hall of Fame (HOF).  Some of these players have wanted to create a minimum threshold for the number of votes needed to enter the Hall of Fame.

In order to find a good threshold, my friend Wally, a blackjack player, created a simulation.  Here is what he wrote, "The way the voting works currently is: there are 9 candidates and everyone gets to vote for 3 of them. Ballots from members of the HOF count double, so basically they get to vote for the same 3 people twice."  His simulation results for 20 HOF voters and 80 regular voters were

average random max votes ≈ 49.57

standard deviation of max votes ≈ 3.295

I tried and failed to find a way to calculate the distribution of the maximum number of votes for the six candidates without a simulation.  I was able to create a algorithm to solve the following simpler question,

"If there are $r$ voters, every voter votes for exactly one of the $c$ candidates, and all voters are weighted equally, then what is the probability that $\max_i(V_i)=j$ where $V_i$ is a random variable indicating how many votes the $i$th candidate received.

My algorithm runs a little slowly performing order $c\cdot r^3$ calculations to obtain the probabilities.  The only algorithms that I can think of for the original question require something like order $c\cdot r^5\cdot h^5$ calculations where $h$ is the number of HOF voters.

Does anyone know of any faster algorithms for computing the probability that the maximum number of votes among the candidates will equal $j$ for all possible values of $j$?

Does the original question or the simplified question show up in any books on combinatorics?

Comment: What is a max vote [for candidate A]? Is it maximum number of votes A receives, and if so, isn't it just the number of votes A receives?

Comment: @Mike Are you referring to $\max_i(V_i)$ ? If yes, then it's $\max(V_1, V_2 \dots V_c)$

Comment: Also worth noting:  Of course the abstract versions assume independence and equal probabilities, which are not sensible assumptions to make for voting.

Comment: @lulu i believe the purpose is to use random voting as a null hypothesis so as to create a threshold for "yeah, this wasn't chance, there's a clear preference for this candidate"

Comment: @lulu    yes, the simplest question is the duplicate that you indicated.  Thanks!

Comment: @eyeballfrog    Yes, that is correct.  I think that they want to create a threshold with a "p" value like 0.01 to reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: @lulu, for the simplest question, I was able to create a recursive formula for $p(i, m,v)$, the probability that the maximum number of votes among the first $i$ candidates is $m$ and the number of votes remaining is $v$ in terms of the value of $p$ for fewer candidates.

Comment: Good.  Not following the null hypothesis bit though.  These are votes, we know they aren't chance.  You are, of course, free to discard some candidates with too few votes, but I don't see any statistical issues there.  Nor do I see the point, unless you are talking about ranked choice or the like.